# showing there exists a subgroup of G (abelian finite no cyclic) that is isomorphic to Z/pZ × Z/pZ for a prime number p.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let be G an abelian finite group. We suppose that G is not cyclic. We have to show that there exists a subgroup of G that is isomorphic to $Z/pZ \times Z/pZ $ for a prime number p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the classification theorem for finitely-generated abelian groups, there are primes $p_1,\dots,p_r$ and positive integers $k_1,\dots,k_r$ such that
$$ G\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p_1^{k_1}\mathbb{Z}\times\dots\times \mathbb{Z}/p_r^{k_r}\mathbb{Z}$$

If the primes $p_i$ were distinct then $G$ would be cyclic, so since $G$ is not cyclic at least two of the $p_i$ are equal, say $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Setting $p=p_1=p_2$, it follows that $G$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k_1}\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p^{k_2}\mathbb{Z}$, hence contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations it is pretty clear i didnt think this way